# input .on('keydown') not working at first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want use `.on()` for listening some event of input text in my jquery and this is my code, but it's not working on keydown in first time i pressed a key:

```
$(s.join(", ")).on('keyup paste change focus blur keydown', function(e)
{
   if($(e.target).val()!='')
       console.log(e.which);
})
```

Comment: The way you hook that event handler up seems fine, my bet is that your selector will not match your textbox(es). Can you tell us the value of `s`?

Comment: `console.log(s.join(", "))` and let us know what comes up

Comment: I have pushed some selectors in s:  `s.push('input[data-input_id=firstId]');`, it's works fine with keyup paste focus blur ... but the problem is keydown, it works but not at first time

Comment: @PatsyIssa it's result: [13:20:49.286] "input[data-input_id=topNavigBar_SearchInput], input[data-input_id=drawer_popup_SearchInput], input[data-input_id=setdevice_popup_renameInput], input[data-input_id=has_holdertext]"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the solution I think, it's need just some little sleep (It's working :-O ) :

```
$(s.join(", ")).on('keyup paste change focus blur keydown', function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if($(e.target).val()!='')
           console.log(e.which); 
    },1);
});
```

Comment: This is no different than giorgio's, except it has an awful implementation of setTimeout() so is calling that function every millisecond.

Comment: no! it's so different, when you have a field in your web page and browser saved value of that field for suggest, when field has been filled by browser, no event getting raise, because browser filling that field before than runing any scripts.

Answer (score 6):

The keydown event gets fired, but by then the character isn't added yet. So checking if the value is empty won't do. You should try something like this:

```
$(s.join(", ")).on('keyup paste change focus blur keydown', function(e)
{
if($(e.target).val()!='' || e.type == 'keydown')
    console.log(e.which);
})
```

For a demonstration of the values at keydown and keyup, check http://jsfiddle.net/vtUdE/ (look in your console log)

Comment: It's not what i want i've use something like this but when input is empty and you press `Backspace` it's trigging: `vl = $(e.target).val();
  if(e.type == 'keydown') {
    vl += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  }
  if((vl != '')) {//somecode}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use keypress() instead:

```
$(s.join(", ")).keypress(function(e) {
  console.log(e.which);
});
```

Make sure your selector $(s.join(", ")) is returning an element (not null)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `keydown` is not working?

Try this and write us the result

`console.log(e.type + ':' + e.which)`;

Here is a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/3F9FP/

Answer (score 0):

Following your comment above:

```
input[data-input_id=topNavigBar_SearchInput], input[data-input_id=drawer_popup_SearchInput], input[data-input_id=setdevice_popup_renameInput], input[data-input_id=has_holdertext]
```

In these selectors, the ids should have quotes around them. Hence your selection should look like this:

```
$("input[data-input_id='topNavigBar_SearchInput'], input[data-input_id='drawer_popup_SearchInput'], input[data-input_id='setdevice_popup_renameInput'], input[data-input_id='has_holdertext']").on('...
```

Try hard coding the selectors like I've posted here and see if the event handler works.

Comment: it's not id ! it's data, and handles fine, the problem is not this

Comment: Did you try hard coding it?

Comment: It's the solution I think, it's need just some little sleep (It's working :-O ) :

`$(s.join(", ")).on('keyup paste change focus blur keydown', function(e)
 {
 setTimeout(function() {
 if($(e.target).val()!='')
 console.log(e.which);
 },1);`

Comment: No matter what attribute you check against, the inner condition always has quotes!

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla javascript, you can attach "input" event to input field and grab the value instantly.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="text-input" value="" />
```

Javascript:

```
function handleInput(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value)
}

const textInput = document.querySelector("input[name='text-input']");
textInput.addEventListener("input", handleInput);
```